# Заменить ссылки при помощи js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Сервер выдает ссылку, вида

```html
<a href='xxx' class=''>yyy</a><a class='' href='xxy'>yyx</a>
```

а нужно

```html
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="xxx" class="nav-link ">yyy</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="xxy" class="nav-link ">yyx</a>
</li>
```

ссылок примерно 10-15 как сделать подскажите, спасибо!

Comment: Покажите как получаете данные от сервера. Или просто строкой в 2 ссылки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let html = "<a href='xxx' class=''>yyy</a><a class='' href='xxy'>yyx</a>";

html = correct(html);
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', html);

/***/

function correct(html) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = html;
  
  div.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => {
    a.classList.add('nav-link');
    a.outerHTML = '<li class="nav-item">' + a.outerHTML + '</li>';
  });
  
  return div.innerHTML;
}
```

```css
.nav-item { color: blue; }
.nav-link { color: red; }
```

Comment: Неужели проще без jquery не получится?((

Comment: @Leonid кажется нет) Всё равно надо делать какой-то перебор, добавить класс, завернуть в li... Можно еще регулярным выражением делать `.replace()` но регулярки сложнее редактировать спустя время, + в них легко ошибиться с HTML. Встроенные методы браузера надежнее)

Comment: ламает шаблон...думаю из-за div!

Comment: получилось спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Думаю вам поможет функция [`.wrap()`](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B) у jQuery.

```js
$('a')
  .addClass('nav-link') // Добавим класс, как было в примере
  .wrap('<li class="nav-item">'); // Обернём ссылки li.nav-item
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href='xxx' class=''>yyy</a><a class='' href='xxy'>yyx</a><a href='xxx' class=''>yyy</a><a class='' href='xxy'>yyx</a><a href='xxx' class=''>yyy</a><a class='' href='xxy'>yyx</a><a href='xxx' class=''>yyy</a><a class='' href='xxy'>yyx</a><a href='xxx' class=''>yyy</a><a class='' href='xxy'>yyx</a><a href='xxx' class=''>yyy</a><a class='' href='xxy'>yyx</a><a href='xxx' class=''>yyy</a><a class='' href='xxy'>yyx</a><a href='xxx' class=''>yyy</a><a class='' href='xxy'>yyx</a><a href='xxx' class=''>yyy</a><a class='' href='xxy'>yyx</a><a href='xxx' class=''>yyy</a><a class='' href='xxy'>yyx</a>
```

Comment: кроме етих ссылок есть еще куча(